# Generalization of the Riesz-Markov theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

So, my professor mentioned a version of the Riesz-Markov theorem for some kind of general spaces, that yields a maximum and a minimum measure rather than a unique measure (or something along those lines). He said it applies to Hausdorff locally compact spaces, but I am sure that is probably not it, since the normal version still applies (or maybe it applies to all continuous functions, not only the compactly supported ones...). Does anyone know where I can find this version?